# Do we need Time Travel?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have the tag [time-travel](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-travel) which is inconsistently used. I thought to fix it but I am still unclear where to keep it or even if we need it?

Currently, it's used for the genre, plot device, and for closed off-topic questions such as IDs.

So do we even need this tag or should we limit its use? I did try to discuss it in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/47453673#47453673) but there was no clear conclusion.

Comment: You can always go back in time and stab the person who created it ;)